# NavigationBar Height without using NavigationController In iOS11

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios11

As below, I set NavigationBar Height without using NavigationController.
(use navigation bar as a standalone object)

```
UINavigationBar* navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];

UINavigationItem* navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"];

UIBarButtonItem* cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(onTapCancel:)];
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBtn;

UIBarButtonItem* doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(onTapDone:)];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneBtn;

[navbar setItems:@[navItem]];
[self.view addSubview:navbar];
```

But it doesn’t work on iOS11 beta.
Actually, the NavBar Height looks always default Height = 44.
It works before iOS10.

I tried beta7, but nothing changes.
Is there any way to set NavigationBar Height?

**addition**
I tried to apply Autolayout Constraint like following code.
In this case, "leadingAnchor", "topAnchor", "widthAncohr" works as I expected.
but I couldn't control "heightAnchor".
This is tried on iOS11 GM version.

```
UINavigationBar* navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
navbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

UINavigationItem* navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"];

UIBarButtonItem* cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(onTapCancel:)];
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBtn;

UIBarButtonItem* doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(onTapDone:)];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneBtn;

[navbar setItems:@[navItem]];
[self.view addSubview:navbar];

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[[[navbar leadingAnchor] constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor constant:0]]];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[[[navbar topAnchor] constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:50]]];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[[[navbar heightAnchor] constraintEqualToConstant:100.0]]];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[[[navbar widthAnchor] constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor]]];
```

Comment: can you add some additional code

Comment: sorry, I added. but it's just simple sample code.

Comment: The navigationBar uses autolayout to layout the subviews. Try adding a constraint with for the height anchor like:

'[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[[[navBar heightAnchor] constraintEqualToConstant:40.0]]];'

Comment: I have a similar issue. Any news on this?

Comment: @Kai I edit additional part on my post. I've not found the way to resolve this problem...

Comment: @ntmy I gave up on trying to use a standalone navigation bar. Instead I am now always presenting my view controllers in navigation controller which just works fine. I can modify the navigation bar on the navigation controller just like I want to.

Comment: @Kai I see. If there is restriction to use standalone navigation, this answer at forum may be useful.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/259219#259219

Comment: Your code is fine it's an issue with xcode9. Try to build it with xcode8.3.3 and it will look normal as expected.